# Four conditions in while controller jmeter don't working

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I want to check four condition in while controller in jmeter.
It doesn't working.

It my example :

`${__javaScript(( '${counterSWDOD}'<'${liczbaiteracji}' && ${SW_KWOTA_800_INT} != 800 && ${CODE_DANYCH_DODATKOWYCH_INT != 200 && ${CODE_BADANIA_INT} != 200 ))}`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Here:

   > `'${counterSWDOD}'<'${liczbaiteracji}'`

   you're comparing 2 strings using `<` operator, remove the quotation marks
2. And here:

   > `${CODE_DANYCH_DODATKOWYCH_INT`

   you miss the closing brace `}`

Amended condition:

```
${__javaScript(${counterSWDOD} < ${liczbaiteracji} && ${SW_KWOTA_800_INT} != 800 && ${CODE_DANYCH_DODATKOWYCH_INT} != 200 && ${CODE_BADANIA_INT} != 200, )}
```

---

Just FYI: using __javaScript() function is some form of a performance anti-pattern, consider switching to [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) or [__groovy()](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) function.

Moreover [Nashorn engine has been removed in JDK 15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372) so you won't be able to run your script on later versions of JVM (maybe it's your case already) so consider migrating.